# Print_r errors without Array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I am just coding a website and have stumbled across a problem that I could not solve utilizing popular search engines.

Question: How do I print_r Arrays without displaying unnecessary text?
Example: 'Array()' before displaying the error.

Example: PHP CONFIG CODE

```
if(isset($submit))
{
$errors = array();

if( $password == $username )
{
    $errors[] = 'Same Username and Pass';
}
if( $userlen < 8 )
{
    $errors[] = 'Username must be atleast 8 characters.';
}
if( $userlen > 32 )
{
    $errors[] = 'Username must only contain 32 characters';
}

if (count($errors) == 0)
{
    require 'db/connect.php';
    $insertUser = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('$username','$password')";
    mysql_query($insertUser);
}
} 
?>
```

Code where I call the error array:

```
<div id='errs'>

<?php 
print_r($errors);
?>

</div>
```

This is an example of the result: ' Array ( [0] => Username must be atleast 8 characters. ) ' I want this to read simply 'Username must be atleast 8 characters'.

Thanks in advanced! -And sorry about the noob question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Stop using MySQL_* it's deprecated.
2. Prepare / sanitize your statements.
3. Use MySQLi_*

   ```
   <?php if(!empty($errors)) {?>

   <div id='errs'>

   <?php 
   foreach($errors as $error)
   {
   echo $error;
   }
   ?>

   </div>

   <?php } else {} ?>
   ```

Comment: Getting This: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/directory/public_html/include/footer.php on line 5, I dont know why I am getting this....

Comment: @EugeneStamp are you passing the `$errors` variable to the footer file? If not then there's you're problem

Comment: I think you mean `if (!empty($errors))`. The $error variable is set to an empty array if $submit is set. empty() also doesn't error on unset variables like isset().

Comment: <?php 
require 'err_check.php';

foreach ($errors as $eachError) {
    echo $eachError;
}
?>

Comment: When the $error is echoed out, it reads fine, without the array, however I still get an error on my foreach that looks like this: 'Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'. I guess I'll have to keep error_reporting(0);

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is to loop through the array, check out a foreach statement [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) where you would loop through the $errors array.

```
foreach ($errors as $eachError) {
    echo $eachError;
}
```